# Mouse Wheel not working after updating ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, mouse-wheel

I've recently updated my ubuntu 16.04, and find that my mouse wheel stopped working.
I've tried the 'imwheel' package solution but not solved.
What should I do?

Comment: Any logs from journal or from kmesg?

Comment: @Biswapriyo
No... i've also tried the 'xev' command but no logs appear in  the console but the movement and the clicks :(